# How come there aren’t any Mira Nova toys?

Tags: toys, toy-story

In case none of you have seen *Buzz Lightyear of Star Command*, Mira Nova is the female lead in it. She is the Princess of the planet Tangea and joins Buzz Lightyear’s partner team of Team Lightyear.

When the tv series was new, there were toys of XR, Booster (the other 2 Team Lightyear members), Warp Darkmatter (Buzz’s former partner) and Zurg, but none of Mira Nova.

Why was that?

Comment: Aside from the myriad of Happy Meal toys, you mean? https://www.pinterest.jp/pin/325385141801909158/

Comment: They also didn't do one of Commander Nebula. I guess several minor characters with limited fan-appeal just didn't make the cut. They only made two "waves" of five toys each, and both waves had multiple Buzz action figures in different outfits.

Comment: I've contacted all three of the show's producers via twitter (and the actor who voiced that character). Hopefully one of them will respond and give us the inside scoop although I suspect the answer will be *"because we didn't think they'd sell very well"*

Comment: @Valorum I had no idea of the Happy Meal toys until u showed me. I guess I just mean toys that sold in the Disney Store outlets. And as for contacting the makers of that TV show and the actress, I didn’t mean 2 put pressure on u, so honestly, plz don’t kill urself 4 me.

Comment: Ten seconds of research and thirty seconds of twitting is hardly going to ruin my lifestyle

Comment: @Valorum That’s OK then.

Comment: @Valorum Can you please upload a link to the tweets you did to the people behind the Buzz Lightyear TV show for me?

Comment: Sure thing; ([1](https://twitter.com/Answerguesser40/status/1137770127603261440), [2](https://twitter.com/Answerguesser40/status/1137769890482446337), [3](https://twitter.com/Answerguesser40/status/1137768757940686850))

Comment: @Valorum - Which often means that they don't think people will buy female action figures.

Comment: @Adamant - Having basically been bullied into overstocking Black Widow toys in 2019 and Rey dolls in 2018, stores are having to remainder/discount-dump a lot more dolls.